# How to make this image blur with css

Tags: html, image, css, blur

The below is the image which is already blur i mean i want to make other image blur like that image.

Below image with blur to make like the below image

[image: This]

The below image without blur but want to make like above image

[image: this2]

The below is code i tried i don't know whether i correctly did or not i mean blur takes more effect to the image i just want to make light blur.

```css
img {
    filter: blur(1px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
        -moz-filter: blur(1px);
        -o-filter: blur(1px);
        -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Cdd4Es3.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: You can increase the value more than 1px to see the result

Comment: @AhmadAlfy my problem is image is changing more darken i want to make light blur

Comment: Your image is dark. Blurring will eventually average out to the dominate color, which looks like it'll be close to black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a gradient overlay

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .8));
}
img {
  display: block;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Cdd4Es3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple filters to get a desired result. I would add a brightness filter and increase the brightness of the image to 200%.

```
img {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(200%) blur(1px);
  filter: brightness(200%) blur(1px);
}
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ca1ptk47/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding one more css filter to lighten up the img like;

brightness(110%);

```
img {
    filter: blur(1px) brightness(110%);
        -webkit-filter: blur(1px) brightness(110%);
        -moz-filter: blur(1px) brightness(110%);
        -o-filter: blur(1px) brightness(110%);
        -ms-filter: blur(1px) brightness(110%);

}
```